# Django page not found (404) error I think there is some mistake in urls and in edit.html in forms action

Tags: python, html, django, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCxsE.png)This is my edit.html

```
    <form method="POST" action="update/{{i.id}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="p-4 border rounded" onsubmit="myFunction()" >
    {%  csrf_token %}
      {% comment %} <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="UabxqpD8HGPOu1ZSFnIHAPbMtRgWBAnVHEs8bLDx0HnxN6uhG3LyYvZShvcx1ekn"> {% endcomment %}
      
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="full_name">Full Name :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value ={{ i.full_name}} name="full_name" id="id_full_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
        </div>
      </div>   

      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="recruiter_name">Recruiter Name :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{ i.recruiter_name }} name="recruiter_name" id="id_recruiter_name" placeholder="Enter Recruiter Name">
        </div>
      </div>     


      {% comment %} <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
        <label class="text-black" for="id_last_name">Last Name :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="id_last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
        </div>
      </div> {% endcomment %}
    
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="email">Email :</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control"  value ={{i.email }} name="email" id="id_email" placeholder="Enter Email">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="noticeperiod">Notice Period (in Days) :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{i.noticeperiod }} name="noticeperiod" id="notice_period" placeholder="Notice Period">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="preferredlocation">Current Location :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{i.preferredlocation}} name="preferredlocation" id="preferred_location" placeholder="Enter Current Location">
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="expectedlocation">Expected Location :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{i.expectedlocation}} name="expectedlocation" id="expected_location" placeholder="Enter Multiple Locations seperated by comma">
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="currentctc">Current CTC (Per Annum) :</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"   value ={{i.currentctc }} name="currentctc" id="current_ctc" placeholder="Current CTC">
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="expectedctc">Expected CTC (Per Annum) : </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{i.expectedctc }} name="expectedctc" id="expected_ctc" placeholder="Expected CTC">
        </div>
      </div>
      
       <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" for="status">Status : </label> </br>

          <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control"  value ={{i.status }}>
            <option value="Shortlisted">Shortlisted</option>
            <option value="Not Shortlisted">Not Shortlisted</option>
            <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
          </select>
          {% comment %} <input type="text" class="form-control" name="status" id="status1" placeholder="Enter Application Status"> {% endcomment %}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <label class="text-black" >Upload CV</label></br>
          <input type="file"  name="cv" id="cv1"   value ={{ i.cv}} >
        </div>
      </div>


  
      <div class="row form-group mb-4">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value={{i.gender}}>
            
            <label class="form-check-label" for="male">Male</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value={{i.gender}}>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="female">Female</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="submit" value="Update" id ="submit" class="btn px-4 btn-primary text-white">

           {% comment %} <a href="{% url 'jobapp:jobconfirm' %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg">Sign Up</a> {% endcomment %}
        </div>
      </div>
```

May be some problem is there in the form action in urls during submit of this form I mean when I am clicking this Update button I am getting page not found error 404

This is my views.py

```
def delete(request, id):
    i = ApplyForm.objects.get(id = id)
    i.delete()
    return redirect('account:dboard')


def edit(request, id):
    i = ApplyForm.objects.get(id = id)
    context = {
        'i' : i
    }
    return render(request, 'account/edit.html', context)

def update(request, id):
    i = ApplyForm.objects.get(id = id)
    i.full_name = request.POST['full_name']
    i.email = request.POST['email']
    i.noticeperiod = request.POST['noticeperiod']
    i.preferredlocation = request.POST['preferredlocation']
    i.expectedlocation = request.POST['expectedlocation']
    i.currentctc = request.POST['currentctc']
    i.expectedctc= request.POST['expectedctc']
    i.recruiter_name = request.POST['recruiter_name']
    i.status = request.POST['status']
    i.gender = request.POST['gender']
    i.cv = request.POST['cv']
    i.save()
    return redirect('account:dboard')
```

and urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('employee/register/', views.employee_registration, name='employee-registration'),
    path('employer/register/', views.employer_registration, name='employer-registration'),
    path('applyform/', views.applyform, name='applyform'),
    path('dboard/', views.dboard, name='dboard'),
    path('export_excel/', views.export_excel),
    path('delete/<id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('edit/<id>/', views.edit, name='edit'),
    path('update/<id>/', views.update, name='update'),
    path('profile/edit/<int:id>/', views.employee_edit_profile, name='edit-profile'),
    path('login/', views.user_logIn, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logOut, name='logout'),
]
```

and this is models.py

```
class ApplyForm(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300)
    noticeperiod = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    preferredlocation = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    expectedlocation = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    currentctc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    expectedctc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    recruiter_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 300,  null=True, choices= CATEGORY_CHOICES )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='')
```

Whats happening I dont know When I am clicking on update button to update my form in edit.html it shows page not found (404) request method post. I just want that update button working I think something wrong in forms action =/update

Answer (score 0):

Apparently two possible issues that may cause this:

Your form URL does not have an ID, so your form looks like this `<form ...="/update/">`

There is a setting in settings.py - `APPEND_SLASH` - which may be false.
So your url looks like this `/update/ID` instead of this `/update/ID/`.

Check if it has an ID: open the site and right-click, select show source and inspect the form element to verify that it indeed has an ID.

Set `APPEND_SLASH` to true or add the trailing slash to your form item: `action="/update/{{i.id}}/"`

Comment: I am not getting the setting of APPEND_SLASH in settings.py there is nothing called APPEND_SLASH and I have tried this action="update/{{i.id}}/" but still getting same error.

Comment: I have attached an error screenshot see that once

Comment: as you can see, the url is entirely different to what you have in urls.py, the url. you are using an address relative to your current path and not to the base path (base path is localhost:8080/ and the path youre referring is localhost:8080/edit/<id>/update, add a slash in front of update

Comment: Okay I am trying that once

Comment: Its working now but why the url is like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/%2010/ it should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/10/ as the edit is also like this as i am updating 10th record

Comment: tried with int in urls.py but again that page not found error 404 without int its working but url is not some thing I expected